# INSERT Numpy ND array to a MySQL Table

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and I have an ND numpy array named full. It's structure is like this:

```
-------------------
id  |  url  |  date
-------------------
 1     url1    date1
 2     url2    date2
 3     url3    date3
```

and it goes on (up to 300 rows)..I want to insert this array as it is into a mysql database table that has these three columns (i.e. id, url, date). I have heard that there is a MySQLdb library of Python through which I can do it..but not sure how to use it. Please help.

The array is constructed using the following code:

```
with open("samples.txt") as f:
    url = f.readlines()
    f.close
url = map(lambda s: s.strip(), url)

import numpy

url = numpy.array(url)   #url array 1D

dates_array = numpy.loadtxt("m_dates.txt") #dates array 1D

id_array = numpy.arange(0, (len(content)), 1)   #ID array 1D


full = numpy.vstack([id_array, content])
full = full.T
```

Comment: full is the name of the array i am working with..i thought it was obvious. apologies.

Comment: I am sorry for this..what I want is to add this numpy array as it is in the database table which has exact number of columns..this is obvious from the question i guess. Over here, people are supposed to help each other intuitively and helpfully..rather than picking over them and start bashing..this is plain arrogant of some of you. I am sorry for posting.

Comment: I constructed this array..appended it word by word and I am looking to transfer it to the MySQL database table..

Comment: updated the question..i am sorry i wan't getting your point.

Comment: @khan have you looked at http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your edits, it looks like it should have worked:

```
In [6]: full = np.vstack(([1,'a','b'],[2,'c','d'],[3,'e','f']))


In [7]: full
Out[7]: 
array([['1', 'a', 'b'],
       ['2', 'c', 'd'],
       ['3', 'e', 'f']], 
      dtype='|S1')


In [8]: for a,b,c in full:
   ...: print a,b,c
   ...: 
1 a b
2 c d
3 e f
```

You just need to replace the print statement with what ever sql command you want to use.

Comment: This way works..just needed to iterate over each dimension of the ND array. Thank you tcaswell..:-)